# Confluence REST API content not returning results with `Invoke-RestMethod`, but results are visible via web browser

Tags: powershell, confluence-rest-api

I have a Confluence site and I want to pull information about the pages via the [Confluence REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/confluence-server-rest-api/). I'm using a [CQL query](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/advanced-searching-using-cql/): `cql=type=page and space=SpaceName`, so my URI is this:

```
https://<confluence server>/confluence/rest/api/content/search?cql=type=page+and+space=SpaceName
```

I can log into Confluence from a web browser, then navigate to the above URL and I see all the content in JSON format.

However, when I run `Invoke-RestMethod` using the exact same credentials and exact same URI, it's successful but there are 0 results:

```
PS > $uri = "https://<confluence server>/confluence/rest/api/content/search?cql=type=page+and+space=SpaceName"
PS > Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Credential $credential -Method Get

results        : {}
start          : 0
limit          : 25
size           : 0
cqlQuery       : type=page and space=SpaceName
searchDuration : 20
totalSize      : 0
_links         : @{self=https://<confluence server>/confluence/rest/api/content/search?cql=type=page+and+space=SpaceName; base=https://<confluence server>/confluence; context=/confluence}
```

I've also passed the output to a variable (`$results`) and checked the `results` property; it is empty:

```
PS > $results = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Credential $credential -Method Get
PS > [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($results)
True
```

I don't know if the issue is with the Confluence server not acting right, my credentials, or `Invoke-RestMethod`. Is it possible that the Confluence server could be permitting queries/providing different results via a web browser but somehow not via PowerShell?

Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: @mklement0 yes, the `results` are empty.

Comment: @mklement0 for clarification, when I `Format-Custom` the whole result, it returns this:

`Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Credential $credential -Method Get | Format-Custom` > `{ results = [] ... }`

Comment: Thanks for confirming (Indeed, `{}` in the display formatting implies an empty JSON array (`[]`); I originally confused that with the problem of _ostensibly_ missing nested objects, which are merely a _display_ problem, due to the bug reported in [GitHub issue #6163](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6163); simple repro: `'{"results":{"x":{"missing":"from display output"}}}' | ConvertFrom-Json`).

Comment: You can see if adding `-Verbose` offers any additional clues, but I'm not too hopeful.

Comment: @mklement0 oh I see, that makes sense. I tried adding `-Verbose`, but it wasn't very helpful: 

`VERBOSE: GET https://<confluence server>/confluence/rest/api/content/search?cql=type=page+and+space=SpaceName with 0-byte paylod

VERBOSE: received -1-byte response of content type application/json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working. I was using the `-Credential` param with `PSCredential` (which has worked for me in the past with Bitbucket, Confiforms, Jira, etc.). When I switched to the `-Headers` parameter with Basic Auth, it started working as expected:

```
PS > $uri = "https://<confluence server>/confluence/rest/api/content/search?cql=type=page+and+space=SpaceName"
PS > $Headers = @{
    Authorization = "Basic {0}" -f [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("username:password"))
}
PS > Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $Headers -Method Get

results        : {@{id=514598038; type=page; status=current; title=page-title | 20230126-093349 | b05f41c; restrictions=; _links=; _expandable=}, @{id=514428061; type=page; status=current;...}
start          : 0
limit          : 25
size           : 25
cqlQuery       : type=page and space=SpaceName
searchDuration : 36
totalSize      : 6642
_links         : @{self=https://<confluence server>/confluence/rest/api/content/search?cql=type=page+and+space=SpaceName; next=/rest/api/content/search?limit=25&start=25&cql=type=page+and+space=SpaceName; base=https://<confluence server>/confluence; context=/confluence}
```

Somehow, `Invoke-RestMethod` isn't passing the `PSCredential` credentials correctly with the `-Credential` parameter.